# text slider using keyframes animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a slider which contains 3 items, in which everything works good as I want

here is live demo [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/290ruq3g/)

Text slider with 3 items

HTML

```
    <span class="item-1">FAST.</span>
    <span class="item-2">SIMPLE.</span>
    <span class="item-3">PERSONAL.</span>
```

Css

```
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
  color: #cecece;
  background: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-1,
.item-2,
.item-3 {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 2em;
  width: 60%;
  font-size: 2em;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.item-1 {
  animation-name: anim-1;
}

.item-2 {
  animation-name: anim-2;
}

.item-3 {
  animation-name: anim-3;
}

@keyframes anim-1 {
  0%,
  8.3% {
    top: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  8.3%,
  25% {
    top: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.33%,
  100% {
    top: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-2 {
  0%,
  33.33% {
    top: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  41.63%,
 58.29%  {
    top: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  66.66%,
  100% {
    top: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-3 {
  0%,
  66.66% {
    top: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  74.96%,
  91.62% {
    top: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Now I want to two more items to the slider

HTML

```
        <span class="item-1">FAST.</span>
        <span class="item-2">SIMPLE.</span>
        <span class="item-3">PERSONAL.</span>
        <span class="item-4">SOCIAL.</span>             
        <span class="item-5">LOUD.</span>
```

Css

```
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
  color: #cecece;
  background: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-1,
.item-2,
.item-3,
.item-4,
.item-5{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 2em;
  width: 60%;
  font-size: 2em;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.item-1 {
  animation-name: anim-1;
}

.item-2 {
  animation-name: anim-2;
}

.item-3 {
  animation-name: anim-3;
}
.item-4{
    animation-name: anim-4;
}
.item-5{
    animation-name: anim-5;
}

@keyframes anim-1 {
  0%,
  6.3% {
    top: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  6.3%,
  25% {
    top: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  13.33%,
  100% {
    top: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-2 {
  0%,
  23.33% {
    top: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  31.63%,
  48.29% {
    top: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  56.66%,
  100% {
    top: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }

}

@keyframes anim-3 {
  0%,
  56.66% {
    top: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  64.96%,
  71.62% {
    top: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-4 {
  0%,
  71.66% {
    top: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  84.96%,
  91.62% {
    top: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-5 {
  0%,
  84.96% {
    top: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  94.96%,
  91.62% {
    top: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    top: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Here is demo with five items

[not working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tyv924rj/8/)

What do I need to change in my code?

Comment: Not sure I understand fully, but you don't need to duplicate your animation for each element. Just use `animation-delay` and set `animation-iteration-count: 1`, see: https://jsfiddle.net/x4p0vdwb/

Comment: Yes , I need something like that but little bit quick , you can put it as answer I will accept but make it quicker

Answer (score 3):

The problem is due to messed up percentage on the five different animations.

Why not re-use the same animation, something like:

```
@keyframes anim {
  0%, 33.33% {
    top: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33.33%, 50% {
    top: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50%, 100% {
    top: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

and then apply an `animation-delay` on each `span`, something like:

```
.item-1 { animation-delay: 0s }
.item-2 { animation-delay: 4s }
.item-3 { animation-delay: 8s }
.item-4{ animation-delay: 12s }
.item-5{ animation-delay: 16s }
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/d3t8521w/) is a working example.

**Tip** keep in mind that animating `top` value is not the best choice in terms of performance. Try always to animate `transform` and `opacity` values when possible.

Comment: Nice, but the last text is messed up, could you fix that? I'll still upvote you as that is quite a nice solution.

Comment: Probably need touches related on times, here an update faster https://jsfiddle.net/m9tv1qfh/

Comment: @user9964622 to fix the last text, change `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` to `animation-iteration-count: 1;`. What happens is, that the animation restarts after 20s, so the first text comes back when the last text is animating

Comment: Absolutely! or change the values to match the desired behavior.

Comment: @elveti your right but I want the text to loop infinite so if I change, it won't loop forever

Comment: @user9964622 see the edition Asfan made to match `delay` and `duration`

Comment: @LionelT u inspired me so I tried this https://jsfiddle.net/ng4bpmd1/5/ but 4 and 5 element not showing, can you check out?

Comment: You have to modify the `margin-top` to show the last items in the first keyframes (add 400px, 500px).

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
  color: #cecece;
  background: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-1,
.item-2,
.item-3,
.item-4,
.item-5{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: -100%;
  width: 60%;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 2em;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: anim-all;
}

.item-1 { animation-delay: 0s }
.item-2 { animation-delay: 3s }
.item-3 { animation-delay: 6s }
.item-4{ animation-delay: 9s }
.item-5{ animation-delay: 12s }

@keyframes anim-all {
  0%, 33.33% {
    top: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33.33%, 50% {
    top: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50%, 100% {
        top: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
<span class="item-1">FAST.</span>
<span class="item-2">SIMPLE.</span>
<span class="item-3">PERSONAL.</span>
<span class="item-4">SOCIAL.</span>    
<span class="item-5">LOUD.</span>
</body>
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
  color: #cecece;
  background: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-1,
.item-2,
.item-3,
.item-4,
.item-5{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: -100%;
  width: 60%;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 2em;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: anim-all;
}

.item-1 { animation-delay: 0s }
.item-2 { animation-delay: 4.25s }
.item-3 { animation-delay: 8.50s }
.item-4{ animation-delay: 12.75s }
.item-5{ animation-delay: 17s }

@keyframes anim-all {
  0%, 33.33% {
    top: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33.33%, 50% {
        top: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50%, 100% {
        top: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
<span class="item-1">FAST.</span>
<span class="item-2">SIMPLE.</span>
<span class="item-3">PERSONAL.</span>
<span class="item-4">SOCIAL.</span>    
<span class="item-5">LOUD.</span>
</body>
```

Comment: Verry slow , can you mae it  quicker?

Comment: Now, Check it Out. I'm making animation a little bit faster.  @user9964622